# How to automatically generate HTML table from image in Linux?

Tags: linux, images, photoshop

In Photoshop, you can easily divide the image into zones using point and click and it automatically generates the corresponding HTML with image slices addressed in tables. Gimp also has a Slice (Filter > Web > Slice) but it is so rudimentary and, as far as I can see, does not allow point and click selection of slices.

I am wondering if the functionality can be added into Gimp, or there are other Linux software to do this. I hate to return to Windows just to do this simple task which I happen to use frequently. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? If you want to use an image as the background of a fixed-size table, then just set the table's background to the image.

Comment: I need this to make html emails with clickable areas on an image. The click area zones vary depending on the image, hence the requirement to have a point and click slicing capability.

Comment: I would just use an image map for that. According to [Campaign Monitor's tests](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2432/do-image-maps-work-in-html-ema/), all popular web, mobile and desktop email clients support image maps.

Comment: Read the link carefully: "The results indicate that it’s not a good idea to use image maps".

Comment: True. They are discouraged because of image-blocking clients. However, you're using image-based links anyways, so what's the difference?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article http://gimp4you.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/guillotine-the-gimp-way-to-slice-images/ Gimp has slice filters and guillotine transformations that can be used for this.